# Android studio get distance in every 5s

Tags: android, android-studio

No bug, but the distance keeps changing when i click test button(not every 5s), so i dunno if my code really works well or not. It would be appreciated if you can tell whether there is some logical error or not.
here is my code.
The logic here is, when i have clicked start button, it will get the location, and then in every 5s, it will get a new location and calculate the distance and store it in an array. When i press test button, the total distance will be shown

```
public class MapsActivity extends BaseActivity /*implements LocationListener*/{
double totalDis=0;
double l;
int oxy =0;
TimeAnimator anim = new TimeAnimator();
private int isReset = 1;
private TextView textTimer;
private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private Button resetButton;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private GoogleMap mMap; 
private Button testbtn;
double x;
double y;
double j;
double k;
float [] dis = new float[6];
TextView txt;
Location locationA;
Location locationB;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items); // load
    // titles
    // from
    // strings.xml

    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);// load icons from
    // strings.xml

    set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);

    textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);

    testbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbtn);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTest);

    testbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            for(int i=0;i<dis.length;i++){
                totalDis+=dis[i];
            }

            txt.setText("dis = "+totalDis);

        }
    });

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location locationA = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            x = locationA.getLatitude();
            y = locationA.getLongitude();

            anim.start();
            anim.setTimeListener(new TimeAnimator.TimeListener() {
                long time = 0;

                @Override
                public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator timeAnimator, long t, long dt) {
                    time += dt;
                    if (time >= 5000) { // >= needed because this also might be not totally accurate...
                        time -= 5000; // keep the remainder (if there is) to correct the accuracy of next loop

                        // do stuff here (in every 5 seconds)

                        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        Location locationB = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        j = locationB.getLatitude();
                        k = locationB.getLongitude();

                        Location.distanceBetween(x,y,j,k,dis);

                        x=j;
                        y=k;
                    }
                }
            });



        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwap += timeInMillies;
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

        }
    });

    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textTimer.setText("0:00:00");
            timeSwap=0;
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;


        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);


    }

};


}
```

Comment: where is your implementation . what interface you have implemented ?

Comment: what means? i just get the location when startbtn is clicked, and then in every 5s it get a new location and calculate the distance. You can see codes in startbutton

Comment: for getting location there is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

and 

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

thats is locationlistener and googleplay services . which one are you using ?

Comment: LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location locationA = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            x = locationA.getLatitude();
            y = locationA.getLongitude();
here is what i used

Comment: where is requstlocationupdate in your code ??

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long, float, android.location.Criteria, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: i dun have it, but what is it? sry i am new to android, it would be highly appreciated, if you could tell me more, as it is hard for me to make changes of my code

Comment: i will edit your code and give your answer .

Comment: is your map working fine ?

Comment: Yes, all works well, and no bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put these codes into yours as directed .

declair these veriables

```
LocationManager manager;
Button start_calculating, show;
boolean startcount_now = false;
double total_dist = 0;
Location last_loc = null;
```

import

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

and implement

```
LocationListener
```

then implement these methods

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (startcount_now == true) {
        if (last_loc == null) {
            last_loc = location;
        } else {
            total_dist += location.distanceTo(last_loc);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return;
    }
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return;
    }
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.removeUpdates(MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

in oncreate()

```
manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

the listeners for the button (you add these into your own button used for this purpose)

```
start_calculating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startcount_now = true;
        }
    });
    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "total distancetravelled is " + total_dist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

add permission in menifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

the show button will show you the total distance in toast . you can use as you want it. the location fetching will be stopped when your app is in background. for the location fetching mechanism please read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: inside protected void onPause(), what is this doing?checkSelfPermission and requestPermissions cannot resolve, it shows cannot resolve method checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity, String)

Comment: i have commented these stuff, it can run in real device, but the distance is always 0. i should test it outside home, so that the distance will be changed? actually i really wanna use the distance i got to calculate the avg speed in every 5s. If you can help, i wanna post one more thread to ask this.

Comment: hey see the link i have given in last part answer. so you give the min distance or min time. i have given time as 5 seconds so 0 meter distance. so that when time is 5 seconds the location will be provided to you irrespective of the distance you travel.

Comment: if you target sdk is 6.0 then you should check permission or if not then you can delete those lines.

Comment: yep, i have tested it,but i have walked 140m(as shown by google map), and then i use my app to test, it shows a very large number. Also, is there any way to get the device moving speed accurately?

Comment: Is that the testing distance is too short??

Comment: so i should use passive_provider in order to get faster update? But i find that passive provider is not accurate?

Comment: you can do one more thing. give the min time and min distance as  0 , 0 and through a timer take location updates every  5 seconds but the location will be updated conteniously in the background.

Comment: glad that my solution helped you.

Comment: thz for your help, but still its not stable and accurate

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very very wrong.

Refer to [Receiving Location updates](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) page. That page leaves some stuff for you to implement, so I'll give you working example. You'll need to adapt it for your needs yourself.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable final Bundle bundle) {
    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(final int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new LocationChangedEvent(location));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull final ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Logger.e(this, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Utils.showPermissionRationaleDialog(MainActivity.this, R.string.permission_rationale_location,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    } else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                "request_location_updates");
    }
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell why it is very very wrong? I can get the distance between two points, and the TimeAnimator works in every 5s.
i did test it with two buttons to get location, and it works. It would be highly appreciated if you could explain more, as i am new to android, i dunno how to make changes with your code. thz